# Libxml installation issues

Tags: svn, libxml2

Just beginning with svn, but using any svn command from bash outputs the following:

```
svnsync: /usr/local/lib/libxml2.so.2: no version information available (required by /usr/lib/libneon-gnutls.so.27)
svnsync: /usr/local/lib/libxml2.so.2: no version information available (required by /usr/lib/libneon-gnutls.so.27)
```

(And the second one isn't a duplicate; it's what the shell is outputting.)

I found something online (though it's in Spanish) [here](http://www.elotrolado.net/hilo_problema-con-quot-libxml2-quot-y-subversion-en-ubuntu-10-10_1560318), but don't get the output when I plug it through [Google Translate](http://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&sl=es&u=http://www.elotrolado.net/hilo_problema-con-quot-libxml2-quot-y-subversion-en-ubuntu-10-10_1560318&ei=aG3GTtPuO6fh0QHrq4g0&sa=X&oi=translate&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CCIQ7gEwAA&prev=/search%3Fq%3D%2522/usr/local/lib/libxml2.so.2:%2Bno%2Bversion%2Binformation%2Bavailable%2B%28required%2Bby%2B/usr/lib/libneon-gnutls.so.27%29%2522%26hl%3Den%26client%3Dubuntu%26hs%3DdaQ%26channel%3Dfs%26biw%3D1252%26bih%3D623%26prmd%3Dimvns).

I have the same problem, so what do I do?

P.S. I'm running a 32-bit version of Wubi 11.10 Oneiric Ocelot with libxml 2.7.8 installed. Also, here's the relevant terminal commands.

```
user@ubuntu:/tmp/test-svn$ dpkg -L libxml2 | grep '\.so'
/usr/lib/libxml2.so.2.7.8
/usr/lib/libxml2.so.2
user@ubuntu:/tmp/test-svn$ ldd /usr/lib/libneon-gnutls.so.27
# some pkgs
    libxml2.so.2 => /usr/local/lib/libxml2.so.2 (0x00007f6d0f6c6000)
    # more pkgs
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like svn is looking for libxml in `/usr/local` while you have the xml in just `/usr`.  Try copying the .so's to `/usr/local/lib/`.

Comment: This is really awkward...both packages (the `libxml2.so.2` shortcut and the `libxml2.so.2.7.8`) are located in both `/usr/lib/` and `/usr/local/lib`.

Comment: One thing I noticed, though: I have a file named `libxml2.so` in `/usr/local/lib` that does not exist in `/usr/lib`. Could that be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

In `/usr/local/lib/` folder try to move(remove if helps) older versions of `libxml2.so` and leave the most new `libxml2.so.2.7.8` lib